No me cargan los estilos al pasar de ionic a android, segui todos los pasos de la documentacion pero nada

En esta imagen se logra ver que no se estan cargando correctamente,

se deberia ver de esta forma en el dispositivo movil

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

utiliza @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark):
    @import 'variables';
Estilos para el tema blanco (por defecto)
body {
  background-color: $white-primary;
  color: $white-text;
}

// Estilos para el tema negro
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: $black-primary;
    color: $black-text;
  }
}

Es muy probable que tu tema este cargandose negro y este desarrollada para el.blanco
Fuente: https://paginaweb.app/ionic-desarrollar-apps-de-diferentes-temas-oscuro-claro-fallos-al-cargar-css/
